# flex attribute does not work when specified as light DOM

Tags: polymer

I am trying to make "flex" attribute work nicely when it is specified as light DOM. The sample code below is what I have in a custom element that I am working on.

This works:

```
<core-scroll-header-panel fixed>
    <core-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
        <span flex>Hello!</span>
        <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
        <!--<content select="[toolbar]"></content>-->
    </core-toolbar>
    <div content>
        stuff...
    </div>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
```

Content of `select="[toolbar]"` is the same 3 lines in the example above. This does not work. Span does not flex:

```
<core-scroll-header-panel fixed>
    <core-toolbar>
        <content select="[toolbar]"></content>
    </core-toolbar>
    <div content>
        stuff...
    </div>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
```

Any idea how to make this work? I am ok with a solution where I need to place additional styles in the custom element that I am creating but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `select="[toolbar]` on the `<content>` insertion point means that your light dom nodes will need a `toolbar` attribute to be pulled in:

```
<my-element>
  <paper-icon-button toolbar icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
  <span toolbar flex>Hello!</span>
  <paper-icon-button toolbar icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
</my-element>
```

I was able to get this working without issue. It also needed a `fit` layout attr on the `core-scroll-header-panel` to give it a size.

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-scroll-header-panel/core-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <core-scroll-header-panel fit>
      <core-toolbar>
        <content select="[toolbar]"></content>
      </core-toolbar>
      <div content>
        stuff...
      </div>
    </core-scroll-header-panel>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<my-element>
  <paper-icon-button toolbar icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
  <span toolbar flex>Hello!</span>
  <paper-icon-button toolbar icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
</my-element>
```